# It is possible to pass variable Ref cursor of an Oracle stored procedure when called from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I have a problem calling an Oracle stored procedure from SQL Server.
Another system, send me a stored procedure that I need to call, it is not possible to change it, but I am trying to call it from SQL Server.

I created a linked server in SQL Server to Oracle, I have run select queries and if I can retrieve data, the RPC properties are enabled

```
EXECUTE ('begin SP_DETAILS(P_QUALIFIER,P_PORTFOLIO,P_DATE); end;', null, null, null) AT Operadora;
```

***Mens. 7213, Nivel 16, Estado 1, Línea 4
The attempt by the provider to pass remote stored procedure parameters to remote server 'Operadora'  failed. Verify that the number of parameters, the order, and the values passed are correct.***

The parameters that the stored procedure receives in Oracle are the following, but I have problem assigning the `REF CURSOR`, the rest of the parameters are null

```
create or replace PROCEDURE SP_DETAILS ( P_DS_MODEL_PORTF_DET_C IN OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
 P_QUALIFIER IN VARCHAR2,
 P_PORTFOLIO     IN     VARCHAR2,
 P_DATE     IN     TIMESTAMP )
```

Thanks

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 0):

You can access an Oracle REF CURSOR via .NET. If you really need to do this from SQL Server you will have to use the CLR.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I was hoping that if I could get it. I do not know CLR, but I use SSIS only that consuming it takes more time. Will you have links to help me do it with CLR or would it be very complex?